# Magento 2 Why in configuration "Use system value" is disabled

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

In Magento 2 in  configuration section "Use system value" is always disabled.
Can some one please give any idea, wow can I solved i?
Please check attached image.

Thanks in advance for any help. [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3Jxh.png)

Answer (score 1):

Those values are selected by default and you can change those values by un-checking "Use system value" checkbox.
[image]

Comment: "Use system value" is always disable , I can not even click it to make it enable. thanks for your replay

Comment: Do you face same issue even if you switch your store view?

Comment: If I switch store view, it works fine, check box becomes active